# How do I see output of command in grunt-shell-spawn?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-shell

I'm using grunt shell spawn to run jasmine tests. I know this is not the ideal way to run tests on my code. After having unsuccessfully tried other grunt plugins, I have decided that this approach is better given my project structure and all the configs set up around it.

Basically in my project, when I run `jasmine`, I see results on the console like this

[image]

I've set up my grunt shell task for `test` like this

```
'test' : {

        'command' : 'jasmine',

        'options' : {

          'async' : true

        }
 }
```

So that when I run `grunt test`, I see the same output as above. Instead, I see this

[image]

The above picture tells me nothing about how many tests passed or failed. It simply tells me that command got successfully executed.

What option(s) should I add in my `test` task of my `grunt-shell-spawn` so that the output looks like the first image instead of the second?

Comment: Are you using this https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn

Comment: Yes. I tried setting the stdout too. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I subverted my problem by spawning a new window with `start` command.

```
'test' : {

    'command' : 'start jasmine',

    'options' : {

      'async' : true

    }
}
```